# How does one efficiently go about researching the history of a specific issue across state legislatures?

Tags: united-states, us-state-laws, state-legislatures, legislature

I am attempting to research a certain political issue across state legislatures.

Specifically, I'm attempting to compile information regarding which states have debated a specific issue in their legislature recently, as well as the results of any proposed bill, data on who sponsored the bill, those persons' voting records, etc.

I have had some success compiling this information by going to individual state legislature's websites. However, many of them don't appear to publish much of this data online.

How does one go about conducting such political research? Is there any sort of service providing a centralised database?

Comment: I should probably clarify for context that I am attempting to do this on behalf of an NGO, and thus an existing compilation from an advocacy organisation does not yet exist regarding the issue.

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include that clarification.

Answer (score 2):

[NCSL 50-State Searchable Bill Tracking Databases](https://www.ncsl.org/research/telecommunications-and-information-technology/ncsl-50-state-searchable-bill-tracking-databases.aspx)

> Find the most comprehensive and complete 50-state information in NCSL's searchable bill tracking databases. Select a topic listed below to find complete bill information. The status of bills listed in these databases is updated every week. Search by subtopics, year, status (e.g., pending, enacted, to governor, etc.) or enter keywords to identify bills.
>
> If your issue of interest is not listed here, enter topic terms in the white search box at the upper right of any NCSL webpage for additional resources.

Comment: Many thanks! Apologies- I've since slightly amended the question. I am attempting to do this on behalf of an advocacy organisation, and thus an existing compilation of data concerning the issue does not yet exist.

Answer (score 0):

[Legiscan](https://legiscan.com/) offers a free service which allows one to do full-text searches on proposed legislation, and sort the bills by year, etc... It also provides information concerning whether or not the bill passed, voting records, and direct links to the relevant webpages of state legislatures.

Thus, it is useful for researching specific issues and proposed solutions across states.